# can't find the error in json document

Tags: javascript, json

I cannot find the error in this json document, I have tried to validate it on jsonlint, but cannot understand the error.

```
{
"type": "mongodb",
"mongodb": {
    "servers": [
        {
            "port": 27017,
            "host": “abc.com”
        }
    ],
    "options": {
        "secondary_read_preference": true
    },
    "db": “abc”,
    "collection": “abc”
},
"index": {
    "name": “abc”,
    "type": “id”
}
}
```

here is the jsonlint result screenshot
[image]

please explain what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are using wrong double quotes, you should use `"` instead of `”`